# Issue in Passing data from UicollectionView controller

Tags: ios, swift3

I have seen couple of posts but not able to figure out the issue

I want to pass data from UICollectionView Controller to my UIViewController , Here are the details

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Selection2" {

        if let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPath(for: sender as! UICollectionViewCell) {

            let detailVC = segue.destination as! SelectionViewController
            //
            let item = items1[indexPath.row]

            //passing the item name which is selected 
            detailVC.label1.text = item.name1


        }
    }
}
```

And here is the  SelectionViewController code :

```
import UIKit

class SelctionViewController: UIViewController {

var label1 : UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


  Label.text = self.label1.text



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

}
```

But when i run this i am not able to pass values and getting the following error :

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Please suggest how this can be corrected , Thanks

Comment: i'd say that either the `sender` is not a `UICollectionViewCell` or the `segue.destination` is not a `SelectionViewController`. can you add an exception breakpoint to see where exactly the app crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you the following approach. write below code in didSelectItemAt method.

```
let detailVC  = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Selection2") as! SelectionViewController
let item = items1[indexPath.row]

//Create string property itemName and pass the value
detailVC.itemName = item.name1

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
```

Assing itemName to laber in SelectionViewController like below.

*self.Label.text = itemName*

Comment: i tried your suggestions and did the following changes :  var itemName : String!      and then calling the value like this in the code self.Label.text = itemName   , it is not crashing but not showing anything in the label view , i checked and it is connected properly as Outlet

Comment: any insights why the value is not being displayed?

Comment: @GS Can you please put break points in didSelectItemAt  method and check item.name1 is having value or not.

Comment: @GS Can you please post your latest code because it is working fine for me

Comment: Thanks , it is now working fine , there was issue with didSelect method  which i was using override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { let detailVC  = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Selection2") as! SelctionViewController
       
        
       
        
        detailVC.itemName = self.items1[indexPath.row].name1
        
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true) }

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using UIlabel label1, declare string variable eg. title. and Change the following lines in your code.

**class SelctionViewController: UIViewController {**

```
var title = ""

@IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   Label.text = title
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
```

**prepareForSegue method:** instead of detailVC.label1.text, use detailVC.title

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if segue.identifier == "Selection2" {

    if let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPath(for: sender as! UICollectionViewCell) {

        let detailVC = segue.destination as! SelectionViewController
        let item = items1[indexPath.row]

        detailVC.title = item.name1 // instead of detailVC.label1.text, use detailVC.title

    }
}
}
```

Comment: it's working fine for me but i have edited as per your code.

Answer (score 0):

@lazyCoder , thanks for helping me out

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let detailVC  = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Selection2") as! SelctionViewController

    detailVC.itemName = self.items1[indexPath.row].name1


self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)

}
```

This code is working perfectly fine now ..Cheers